# Unable to display multiple rows only a single row is being returned

Tags: php, mysql, sql, database

The code written below is returning only a single record, altough my query is returning multiple records. So how can i display the multiple rows?

```
    $stmt->bind_result($u_id,$cust_name,$u_name,$cnic,$address,$password);

                    $stmt->fetch();

                    $user = array(
                    'cust_name'=>$cust_name, 
                    'u_name'=>$u_name, 
                    'cnic'=>$cnic,
                    'address'=>$address,
                    'password'=>$password,
                    'u_id'=>$u_id
                    );

                    $response['user'] = $user; 

                    $stmt->close();
```

Comment: `while( $stmt->fetch() ){/* output*/}`

Comment: I tried it, it just returns the last row,

Comment: `$response['users'][] = $user;`

Comment: @Phil where to write it inside the while loop or outside the loop??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps you need to try like this. The array is being over written on each iteration ( assuming in the loop )

```
$user=array();          
$sql='select `u_id`,`cust_name`,`u_name`,`cnic`,`address`,`password`
        from `TABLE`';
$stmt=$db->prepare( $sql );
$stmt->execute();
$stmt->store_result();
$stmt->bind_result($u_id,$cust_name,$u_name,$cnic,$address,$password);

while( $stmt->fetch() ){
    $user[] = array(
        'cust_name' =>  $cust_name, 
        'u_name'    =>  $u_name, 
        'cnic'      =>  $cnic,
        'address'   =>  $address,
        'password'  =>  $password,
        'u_id'      =>  $u_id
    );
}
$stmt->close();
```

Comment: Do you actually need `store_result()` for this?

Comment: I had always been under the impression that it was required but if you think not then probably not...

Comment: I think it is if you want `num_rows` but if you're just iterating the statement cursor with `fetch()`, I'm pretty sure it's un-needed

Comment: good to know.. thanks for the info ~ makes it quicker to code with fewer things to type.

Answer (score 0):

`fetch` fetches a single row every time it is called, untill rows are completed. So you should do:

```
$stmt->bind_result($u_id,$cust_name,$u_name,$cnic,$address,$password);

                while($stmt->fetch()) {

                $user = array(
                'cust_name'=>$cust_name, 
                'u_name'=>$u_name, 
                'cnic'=>$cnic,
                'address'=>$address,
                'password'=>$password,
                'u_id'=>$u_id
                );

                $response['user'][] = $user; // append to array, not overwrite it
             }
                $stmt->close();
```